# My Javascript in django is only working once

Tags: javascript, python, django

Im creating a online pizza ordering site in django. When the user is ordering the pizza the price of the pizza change according to the selected size of the pizza for this im using javascript to show the price of selected size and hide the remaining.
im using javascript to show the block of selected pizza price and hide the others but the problem is that the javascript only work on the first div when i try to change the size of piza in second div it does nothing.

```js
function selectFunction() {

  var size = document.getElementById("select");
  var option = size.options[size.selectedIndex].text;

  if(option=="Select Size"){
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Rs.";
  }

  if(option=="Large"){
    x = document.getElementById("l-price");
    x.style.display = "block";
    y = document.getElementById("m-price");
    z = document.getElementById("s-price");
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }

  if(option=="Medium"){
    x = document.getElementById("m-price");
    x.style.display = "block";
    y = document.getElementById("l-price");
    z = document.getElementById("s-price");
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }

  if(option=="Regular"){
    x = document.getElementById("s-price");
    x.style.display = "block";
    y = document.getElementById("m-price");
    z = document.getElementById("l-price");
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
{% extends "pizza_app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="md-padding" style="width:92%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
   <form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section-header text-center" >
                <h2 style="color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);">Pizza Menu</h2>
        </div>
        {% for pizza in pizzamenu %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pizza-menu">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center" style="min-width:150px; padding: 0;">
                <div class="menuimg ">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{pizza.image.url}}"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0;" class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding945">
                <div class="menu">
                    <h4>{{pizza.name}}</h4>
                    <span style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"> 
                        <img src="" style="width:130px; margin:0px; margin-top:-35px;">
                        <p id="menup">{{pizza.detail}}</p>          
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 dsize">
                    <div class="form-control ">
                       <select class="select-style" id="select" onchange="selectFunction()">
                            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Size</option>
                            <option value="{{pizza.s_price}}"> Regular</option>
                            <option value="{{pizza.m_price}}"> Medium </option>
                            <option value="{{pizza.l_price}}"> Large</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-7 col-xs-6 " >
                    <h2 style="margin-top:10px;" id="s-price" class="price-position" >Rs.{{pizza.s_price}}</h2>
                    <h2 style="margin-top:10px;" id="m-price" class="price-position" >Rs.{{pizza.m_price}}</h2>
                    <h2 style="margin-top:10px;" id="l-price" class="price-position" >Rs.{{pizza.l_price}}</h2>
                </div>
                    
                <div class=" text-center col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1 add-to-cart">
                    <a class="add-to-cart" href="#" onclick="sizeCheck()">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
         
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </form>
</div>    

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: HTML ids must be unique. You have duplicate ids `select` and `menup`; you need to make them unique in some way, or use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

`id`s must be unique in a document; a single `id` can't refer to multiple elements.

I'd suggest using classes and having an unique ID for the `pizza-menu` element, letting you refer to the price elements via e.g. `document.querySelector('#pizza-123 .l-price')`.

```html
{% for pizza in pizzamenu %}
<div class="..." id="pizza-{{ pizza.id }}">
   <select onchange="selectFunction(this, '{{ pizza.id }}')">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Size</option>
        <option value="{{pizza.s_price}}"> Regular</option>
        <option value="{{pizza.m_price}}"> Medium </option>
        <option value="{{pizza.l_price}}"> Large</option>
    </select>
    <h2 class="s-price">Rs.{{pizza.s_price}}</h2>
    <h2 class="m-price">Rs.{{pizza.m_price}}</h2>
    <h2 class="l-price">Rs.{{pizza.l_price}}</h2>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
function selectFunction(select, pizzaId) {
  var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  var pizzaBlock = document.querySelector('.pizza-' + pizzaId);
  var lPrice = pizzaBlock.querySelector(".l-price");
  var mPrice = pizzaBlock.querySelector(".l-price");
  var sPrice = pizzaBlock.querySelector(".l-price");

  lPrice.style.display = (option === "Large" ? "block" : "none");
  mPrice.style.display = (option === "Medium" ? "block" : "none");
  sPrice.style.display = (option === "Small" ? "block" : "none");
}
```